# Вводное слово "называется"

Tags: грамотная-речь, вводные-слова

Всегда считал, что вводное слово "[называется](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_435)" с оттенком иронии или неодобрения может стоять только в конце фразы. Однако некоторые думают, что может и в начале. Как же на самом деле?

Answer (score 1):

Выражения "и это называется друг", "а ещё называется друг" и т. п. мне слух не режут. В одном из [словарей Лопатина](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=DSeFAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA360&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH2reikt7mAhXGD5oKHaCNCJwQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%22&f=false) есть пример такого употребления. Вот только запятых в подобных случаях мне нигде не удалось найти, что несколько странно.

Comment: Спасибо, grizzly!

Comment: Вопрос возник из-за употребления перед глаголом. Например: *Называется, делай то, не знаю что.*

Comment: @oleedd Не думаю, что мне встречалось такое употребление, но считаю, что оно вполне допустимо в разговорном стиле в определённом контексте. Есть вводное выражение "что называется" и такое его сокращение с оттенком иронии может выглядеть уместно. Замечу только, что пример с идиоматическим выражением не совсем чистый, но это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: "*Что называется*" - употребляется внутри фразы. Вот в конце хуже звучит: *— Ты всё понял? — Нет. Делай то, не знаю что, называется.*

Comment: @oleedd "Что называется" может употребляться и в начале: "что называется, сходили на рыбалку". И это, думаю, придаёт ироничный оттенок (ср. "мы, что называется, сходили на рыбалку"). А Ваш пример ("Делай то, не знаю что, называется") звучит не хуже, я считаю, — похоже, это артефакты субъективного восприятия. И опять же, употребление с идиоматическими выражениями имеют свою специфику.

Comment: У меня "что называется" в начале вообще не звучит, "что" как лишнее, да и на Грамоте примеры только в середине, не думаю, что это случайность. Наверное, "что" употребляется, чтобы вклиниться во фразу. Без него в середине не звучит. Да и смысл другой - "что называется" = "как говорится" (в начале звучит). И на Грамоте тоже об этом сказано. Уже нет значения иронии. То есть перед "рыбалкой" оно не к месту. Вот пример, из-за которого возник этот вопрос: Называется, догадывайся сам, как лучше. Нужно изначально предупредить читателя, что это не призыв к действию, а ирония.

Comment: @oleedd В чём-то я могу с Вами согласиться, в чём-то — нет, но чем дальше, тем более объёмными будут аргументы и потребуется больше примеров. Эта площадка не предназначена для подобных споров, к сожалению (и здесь они пресекаются модераторами).

Comment: А вы что думаете о фразе Олида, Гризли? Об этой: "Называется, догадайся сам, как лучше". И о первой запятой.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Не могу утверждать уверенно. Скорее, я бы не возражал против такого употребления. И лучше с запятой, чем без (впрочем, признаюсь, я не понимаю, почему запятые могут отсутствовать в других примерах — какое-то странное исключение для вводных слов).

Comment: Ясно, спасибо.)